# Process Inbound Emails Failed

Tags: email, cron-job

after update from 4.6.2 to 4.6.9 i have this error in:

Entità: Job Azione: fetch_activities
Summary
Finished execution of Process Inbound Emails with result: Failure, Error message: Process Activities failed

What can i do ?
Thanks

I delete all email account and the error persiste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Review the job log on your scheduled tasks page in the admin menu - the job results there for this task may show an error in them
- Review the PHP error log or output of your cron task which failed
- Review the CiviCRM logfile in `files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.*.log`

You can update your question here with additional details if the solution isn't clear.

Comment: PHP log no error.
This is job log: 
Process Inbound Emails 
Entità: Job Azione: fetch_activities
Summary
Finished execution of Process Inbound Emails with result: Failure, Error message: Process Activities failed
Details


Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Process Inbound Emails with result: Failure, Error message: Process Activities failed

Comment: Marco, is there anything reported on the issue in the CiviCRM log?  (in sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/)

Comment: In ConfigAndLog Oct 15 21:13:57  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => Could not connect to MailStore for iscrizioni@auroratrezzo.it@mail.auroratrezzo.it&lt;p&gt;Error message: &lt;pre&gt;An error occured while sending or receiving mail. The IMAP server did not accept the username and/or password: A0001 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed..&lt;/pre&gt;&lt;p&gt;
    [code] => 
) In thunderbird all are ok.

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks !!!!!! the problem was authentication. I tried via telnet and then everything worked.

Comment: Have added `files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.*.log` to the answer above for future readers. You can mark your the question as answered, this will help future people in the same boat.

Comment: Excuse me Chris, how can i mark my question as answered ??

Comment: See [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) - you can choose the answer which best helped you resolve your question, and that will help future people see what worked for you. Next to the answers, there are vote up and down arrows as well as a checkmark (on your own questions) to accept an answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping build the CiviCRM community knowledge by participating!

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that this occurred because of the upgrade?  You might try to connect to your mail account directly via Thunderbird, Geary, or Outlook using the same connection information in your Mail Accounts admin page.

Also, is it possible that you might have generated a new site key as a result of the upgrade (maybe if you moved the site back and forth with a development copy)?  If so, there's the chance that your password may be garbled because of the change in key.  Try typing the password into your Mail Accounts form again.

Comment: with thunderbird all is ok. I think that is possible to be the site key. How can i regenerate the site key? Can i remove or reset civicrm.settings.php? Thanks

Comment: Don't worry about that. Just enter your password again in Mail Accounts.

Comment: I do it But it did not change anything. how do I debug it or to get more info? HELP HELP :( can i test with url api or ssh or ....