# Process Inbound Emails Failed: No mail protocol

Tags: civimail, scheduled-job

I'm unable to pull activities from an email account. I'm using civicrm 4.5.5 and Wordpress. When looking at the job log I get

```
0
Summary
Finished execution of Process Inbound Emails with result: Failure, Error message: Process Activities failed
Details

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Process Inbound Emails with result: Failure, Error message: Process Activities failed
```

Referencing [Process Inbound Emails Failed](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7030/process-inbound-emails-failed)  I looked at the civicrm error log and got the following error.

```
Oct 10 10:54:38  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => Could not connect to MailStore for @<p>Error message: <pre>Empty mail protocol</pre><p>
    [code] =>
)
```

So it seems like Civi isn't even the information I put in the CiviMail settings. Unlike the question referenced, my problem does not seem to be authentication based. I have an account set up for Email-to-Activity but it doesn't seem to be recognized. Any ideas?

Comment: The question does not specify CiviCRM version or CMS, so answer is for current 4.7 CiviCRM and Drupal. Adjust according to your situation. Linked site is the CiviCRM demo site - see http://demo.civicrm.org for details.

Comment: good point, added, its civi 4.5.5 and wordpress

Answer (score 3):

At **Administer** > **CiviMail** > **Mail Accounts** ([civicrm/admin/mailSettings](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/mailSettings?reset=1)) you want to see two accounts configured, one for **Bounce processing** and one for **Activity processing**

[image: mail accounts]

It's possible what you're describing is what happens when there is *no* account configured for activity processing. If so, the error message is a bit misleading, but I suspect that's what you're seeing. If not, continue :)

Both of these mail accounts require working credentials, see "checking credentials" below.

As well as the username / password correctly set, those mail accounts require a *protocol* - this is probably IMAP, and probably with SSL. (If your mail provider doesn't use SSL, that's bad IMO.)

[image: mail account settings]

#### Checking credentials

Check the mail logins you have work ASAP. You can see the saved password in the DB or by viewing source when editing the account.

I use `fetchmail` to verify this from the server, so I can check access works from the server in question as well. For a Gmail account `bounce@example.org`, this looks like:

```
fetchmail --ssl --check -u bounce@example.org -p imap imap.gmail.com
```

You can also check by adding a mail account to your desktop mail client, just remove it afterwards.

Comment: I made sure by just telneting the mail server, in this case outlook.office365.com. I'm fairly certain that the authentication is not the issue. I would use fetchmail but I'm in a jailshell.

Comment: The lack of upvotes on this answer is criminal.  I'm not sure who to take to CiviCourt over it though.

Comment: @VitoMantese, you don't need to use `fetchmail` from your webserver, you can run the command from any system which can run it. If you can't install fetchmail because it's not available for your OS, you may add the account to any desktop mail app installed on your computer to check if it can connect OK.