# Configuring Inbound Email Config

Tags: email

I used to have CiviCRM Inbound Email processing perfectly, but now it no longer works. Whenever the process is run, I get the following error:

```
Full message: 
Finished execution of Process Inbound Emails with result: Failure, Error message: A fatal error was triggered: Could not connect to MailStore for [prefix]@[domain].org@imap.gmail.com

Error message: 

An error occured while sending or receiving mail. The IMAP server did not accept the username and/or password: A0001 BAD Too many arguments provided 136-v6mb280518080wmm.
```

Please help me fix the config (or if the config is correct I'll set about debugging). The password is functioning perfectly (I emptied it before taking a screenshot of the config). How can I fix this?

[image]

This is for a domain hosted by Google.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess from the error "A0001 BAD Too many arguments provided" and [this unrelated github issue](https://github.com/dlech/gmailbuttons/issues/15) that **you may have a space in your password** (or some other character that needs better handling).

That CiviCRM also triggers "A0001 BAD Too many arguments provided" error suggests CiviCRM doesn't handle spaces in passwords correctly for IMAP/POP3.

Here's some [advice on debugging the inbound mail process in CiviCRM](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15319/process-inbound-emails-failed-no-mail-protocol/15320#15320), which might be useful!

Answer (score 1):

The config looks correct.

Key things to check:

- You can connect to the account using the credentials via the gmail web interface
- You don't have 2FA set up and that less secure apps are allowed for the account
- If the above fails try activating the unlock captcha https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha then test logging in by triggering the scheduled job. You should notice the unlock captcha page change after the log in attempt has finished - you might need to trigger the job again after it's run to connect.
- Finally I'd make sure you can connect to gmail from that server by using something like swaks or similar to connect -> https://serverfault.com/questions/846026/can-i-send-a-mail-through-gmail-with-swaks (Just to make sure you are dealing with a civicrm issue an not a server issue).

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to turn "Less secure apps" ON. More on that here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Clicking "Save & Test" on the Mail Accounts config page still resulted in "An error occured while sending or receiving mail. Failed to connect to the server: :143. (See log for more details.)" error, but triggering the "Process Inbound Emails" job actually worked flawlessly.