# MailStore Error Messages In Log

Tags: email

Getting the following error: Finished execution of Process Inbound Emails with result: Failure, Error message: Could not connect to MailStore for xxxx@xxxx.org@Error message: An error occured while sending or receiving mail. Failed to connect to the server: :995.

This is what the log reads:  Parameters parsed (and passed to API method):
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message:
Finished execution of Process Inbound Emails with result: Failure, Error message: Could not connect to MailStore for xxxxx@xxxxx.org@
Error message:

An error occured while sending or receiving mail. Failed to connect to the server: :995.

I tested the Send Mail and got:  Mail Sent
Sending test email:
From: xxxx@xxxx.org
To: xxx@xxxxx.org
Your SMTP settings are correct. A test email has been sent to your email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though outbound email (SMTP) is configured correctly but inbound email may not be. This could be due to incorrect inbound email settings in CiviCRM or a complication such as two-factor authentication on your email account. These resources may help to pin it down:

- [Configuring Inbound Email Config](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27474/configuring-inbound-email-config)
- [Process Inbound Emails Failed: No mail protocol](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15319/process-inbound-emails-failed-no-mail-protocol/15320#15320)

Answer (score 1):

Based upon davejenx statements I examined the mail settings and changed from POP3 to maildir and it solved the issues. Thanks you for the help!