# Password not accepted for inbound email

Tags: email

I created on our mail server an email account *inbox.civicrm*, and checked it with the webmail facility: username *inbox.civicrm@example.org* and password are working.

Then, i created in CiviCRM an email account with

- server = example.org
- user = inbox.civicrm
- password = same password as used in webmail (tested several times)
- domain name = example.org

But the connection is refused, with SSL or not, POP3 or IMAP.

The error message in the CiviCRM log:

```
(
    [message] => Kan geen verbinding maken met Mailstore voorinbox.civicrm@example.org&lt;p&gt;Foutmelding:&lt;pre&gt;An error occured while sending or receiving mail. The POP3 server did not accept the password: -ERR [AUTH] Authentication failed.
.&lt;/pre&gt;&lt;p&gt;
    [code] => 
)
```

In this question [Process Inbound Emails Failed](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7030/process-inbound-emails-failed/7046), the password was the problem. Where to look for when a wrong password is not the problem?

Drupal 7.35 CiviCRM 4.7.14

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the "fetchmail" approach outlined by Chris Burgess on [this answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/15320/12) is a good troubleshooting step.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up an email client like [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) to connect to your account using IMAP.  That way, you can isolate the problem and avoid any differences in how your webmail login works.

For example, you might find that webmail takes just a username but IMAP/POP wants a domain added to the end, or vice-versa.  Or, you may find that IMAP is turned off (the default in Gmail, for example), or you may need to connect to a different server like imap.example.org or mail.example.org.  Using an IMAP client will give you a little more visibility into what's going on.